# Children's fantasy film, UK TV 70s/80s

Tags: story-identification, movie

This was so long ago I can’t remember if bits of this are dreams or confusions with other things.

I would have seen it on UK TV in the late 70s or early 80s but I feel like it could have been a repeat of earlier, maybe made in the 60s, maybe European or American.

It was in colour, and feels Technicolour in my head.

There was a castle, and a banquet in the castle. A young boy and some friendly monsters/creatures have broken in to the castle to steal/rescue a harp. The harp was big and had the figure of a woman attached and was conscious, could speak.

There was a bit where the boy saw one of his creature friends on the table with an apple stuck in his mouth like a stuffed pig about to be served but then the friend spoke.

That’s all I have.

A fragment that’s stuck in my head for years. 
I search sporadically but nothing comes up.
I brought Singing Ringing Tree recently in case it was that but no cigar.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The motif of a singing harp and a castle is almost certainly Jack and the Beanstalk; http://hero.wikia.com/wiki/Golden_Harp_(Disney)

Comment: [Jack and the Beanstalk (1967)](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x39kevy) (16:09)

Comment: The [1952 version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDNrEtf9rlQ) has a male face. The [1974 version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otHVQVdcvIM) talks but has no face at all

Comment: Thanks for swift responses! It's not any of those though, was live action all the way. I do now remember the 1967 version of Jack though. Maybe it was just a dream!

Comment: There was a [TV adaptation in 1983](https://youtu.be/5uuQ6vxd1NA?t=43m33s). The harp had a woman's face super-imposed on harp strings;

Comment: Disney version here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F__xqjYcF4c but much too early and animated.

Comment: Thanks Valorum, I appreciate your effort. Definitely not one of those though.

Comment: I remember this as a kid. Did the harp play itself?

Comment: Hi Naib - it might have done, i think it was magic in some way. There may have been a flute involved as well.